# Flutter: Convert MaterialColor to string and back to MaterialColor

Tags: android, flutter, colors

I have app that communicates with my API. I need to choose MaterialColor on my flutter app and send it to my API and later get it from API and use it in app. When I send it to my API it looks like this `MaterialColor(primary value: Color(0xff4caf50))` but I can't use it later because it's not possible to cast String like this to Color.

Is there a simple way to reuse color that was sent to API?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, works for me.
First create class for covert hexadecimal to material color

```
class HexColor extends Color {
  static int _getColorFromHex(String hexColor) {
    return int.parse(hexColor, radix: 16);
  }
  HexColor(final String hexColor) : super(_getColorFromHex(hexColor));
}
```

Convert material color to Hexadecimal and send to your API

```
Color materialColor = Colors.blue;
print(materialColor); //MaterialColor(primary value: Color(0xff2196f3))

final hexColor = materialColor.value.toRadixString(16); //convert to hex
//send this value hexColor to your server
...... 
print(hexColor); // ff2196f3 

//how to covert back to material color
print(HexColor(hexColor)); //Color(0xff2196f3)
```

How to use /example getting color from API

```
Container(
  height:300,
  width:300,
  color:HexColor(<color_from_API>),
)
```